# Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method

Tags: java

I need help with the main method, I'm getting this error: while compiling the Project:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:                                                 
   public static void main(String[] args)                                                                                     
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Also tried online Java compilers but no luck.

```
public class Main{
        
        String yourname = "Ayush Sahu";
        int mnumber = 25;
        
        public void justtest(){
            
            System.out.println("This is a test Method!!!");
        }
        
        
    }
    
    class testing extends Main{
        
        String fname = "Balamukunda";
        String lname = "Sahu";
        int age = 25;
        
        public void testing(){
            
            System.out.println("This is a test Method!!!");
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args){
            
            //Accessing the Data of Class: Main
            
            testing myObj1 = new testing();
            
            System.out.println(myObj1.yourname);
            System.out.println(myObj1.mnumber);
            myObj1.justtest();
            
            
            //Accessing the Data of Class: testing
            
            myObj1.testing();
            
            System.out.println(myObj1.fname);
            System.out.println(myObj1.lname);
            System.out.println(myObj1.age);
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Main` class? Why are you extending it? What problem is this inheritance supposed to solve?

Comment: The main method is in the class `testing`, not in the the class `Main`, as the error message is sugesting.

Comment: You must change your MAIN class (which contains main method) in your project by IDE.

Comment: @Some programmer dude : I am new to Java. During practice I got this error.

I want the main method to be in class: testing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run in IDE, right click in middle of testing  class and find *Run -> Run Application* it the dropdown menu and click it. Try to separate each class in individual files. So you must have at least two files: **Main.java** and **testing.java**. I strongly recommend you to use Camel Case for class names and respect coding standard (which mean change *testing* to *Testing* or even better to *Test*).

If not, You must change it in Manifest file or find run configuration in your IDE.